# is it possible to log events of ssis package execution using c# to a file

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, logging

Is it possible to log the events of ssis package execution called from c#

```
 Application app = new Application();
 Package package = app.LoadPackage("<package_path>", null);
 package.ImportConfigurationFile("<configuration_path>");
 DTSExecResult result = package.Execute();
```

I need to log the messages generated during the package execution. I am using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

the Execute method has an overload for "Log"

log
Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSLogging
An IDTSLogging interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.dtscontainer.execute.aspx